# bigcommerce api returning blank results

Tags: bigcommerce

I have downloaded the bigcommerce API and created a test script using the get time sample.
I get a blank response & no error:

My test code is just:

```
<?php
require 'bigcommerce.php';
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
'store_url' => 'https://storeurl.mybigcommerce.com',
'username' => 'apiusername',
'api_key' => 'token'
));

Bigcommerce::setCipher();
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$ping = Bigcommerce::getTime();
if ($ping) echo $ping->format('H:i:s');
?>
```

Can you assist as to why the result is blank ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your cipher is incorrect. 
Please look at the docs http://developer.bigcommerce.com/quickstarts/php

```
Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA')
```